# python функция combinations

Tags: python

```py
from itertools import combinations
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list(combinations(x, 2))
# [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

У меня есть список состоящий из 4 чисел. Мне нужно узнать все пары из этих чисел и после узнать какие из этих пар по сумме равны между друг собой и какое количество таких пар.

Например, для примера на скриншоте получилось 6 пар, из них я могу выделить пару `1, 4` и `2, 3`, ведь их суммы будут равны, если я правильно посчитал, то больше таких пар нет и в итоге в выводе я должен получить 1.

Можно ли как-то взять из этой функции все пары и после сравнить их суммы или нет? Или может это можно сделать как-то по другому, вовсе не использую эту функцию? Да, я конечно мог бы просто посчитать все пары, потом посчитать их суммы и сравнить, но как минимум это дольше, а как максимум чисел может быть не 4, а 14 или еще больше.

Если хотите узнать зачем мне это, то вот сама задача которую я пытаюсь решить:

[image: Задача]

Возможно я вообще не в ту сторону иду, и всё может оказаться куда легче...
(Я хочу сделать это задание конкретно через python, а не excel)

Comment: Текстовую информацию (текст задания, код) нужно добавлять в вопрос текстом, а не скриншотами. [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)

Comment: Есть равные суммы, если `len(set(a + b for a, b in combinations(x, 2))) < 6`

Answer (score 2):

Для решения данной конкретной задачи:

Находим сумму четырёх чисел `S`

Находим максимум и минимум `MX, MN`

Проверяем, что `(MX + MN)*2 == S`.

При выполнении этого условия другое условие `S - MX > MX` для натуральных чисел будет удовлетворено автоматически, как заметил Алексей Р.

Comment: Я хоть и не автор вопроса, но буду благодарен за пояснение необходимости второго условия. Единственная ситуация, которая мне приходит в голову - это наличие нуля.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov В задаче на картинке есть требование - наибольшее число меньше суммы трёх других

Comment: Ах, тыж! Я вообще про первое требование забыл. Спасибо!

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov Ну это автор отвлёк чрезмерным обобщением ;)

Comment: По-моему, первое условие все-таки объективно избыточное при истинном втором. Т.е. если есть две пары натуральных чисел с одинаковой суммой, то любое из чисел всегда строго меньше суммы оставшихся трех. Логика: предположим, что возможен случай Xmax=Xi+Xj+Xk (учитывая, что числа натуральные 1+). Тогда Xmax-Xi=Xj+Xk, что противоречит условию равенства сумм пар. Аналогично при Xmax>Xi+Xj+Xk: тогда и Xmax+Xi>Xj+Xk, что также противоречит условию равенства сумм пар.

Comment: @АлексейР Да, вы абсолютно правы, я, значит, механически выполнил условие...

Answer (score 0):

Простое решение которое вижу я:

Создаём словарь, где ключ - результат сложение, а значение - список пар чисел, которые в сумме дают это самое значение

```py
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
combs = list(combinations(x, 2))

result = {} # Создаём словарь
for comb in combs: # Для каждой комбинации
    s = comb[0] + comb[1] # получаем её сумму

    if s in result: # Если такая сумма уже существует
        result[s].append(comb) # Добавляем комбинацию
    else: # Иначе
        result[s] = [comb] # Создаём новый список с комбинацией comb
```

В итоге получаем такой список:

```py
{3: [(1, 2)], 4: [(1, 3)], 5: [(1, 4), (2, 3)], 6: [(2, 4)], 7: [(3, 4)]}
```

Теперь мы можем просто определить, у какого ключа больше всего список:

```py
max(result, key=lambda comb: len(result[comb])) # 5
```

Сложность алгоритма выходит `O(n)` где `n` - количество комбинаций (если не учитывать обращения к словарю)

Answer (score 0):

В части нахождения пар с одинаковой суммой:

- анализируем сумму четырех чисел - если она нечетная, то пар нет;
- если четная, то берем полусумму;
- берем первое число и отнимаем его от полусуммы (разница);
- пытаемся найти разницу среди оставшихся 3-х чисел;
- если находим, то ставим галку - 2 пары есть.

```
from random import randint

lst = [[randint(1, 10) for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(20)]
cnt = 0
for l in lst:
    s = sum(l)
    if s % 2 == 0:
        if s // 2 - l[0] in l[1:]:
            cnt += 1
            print(f"{l} cодержит 2 пары с суммой = {s // 2}")
print(f'Всего строк с парами с равной суммой = {cnt}')
```

```
[4, 4, 4, 4] cодержит 2 пары с суммой = 8
[1, 2, 2, 1] cодержит 2 пары с суммой = 3
[4, 5, 1, 8] cодержит 2 пары с суммой = 9
[5, 10, 9, 6] cодержит 2 пары с суммой = 15
[4, 5, 7, 8] cодержит 2 пары с суммой = 12
Всего строк с парами с равной суммой = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Я исхожу из вопроса, который Вы предоставили в задании и который стоял перед Вами изначально. `четыре числа разбить на две пары чисел с равными суммами`. Что делает `combinations`: возвращает **все** возможные пары. Но какой смысл сравнивать пары, в которых участвуют одни и те же цифры - это не будет верным решением. Пример:

```
[1, 3, 3, 4]
```

С помощью `combinations` мы получим две пары `(1, 3)`, и такая последовательность подойдет нам. Но это неверно, так как мы два раза использовали одно и тоже число `1`, а судя по условию, мы не можем так делать. Поэтому, решение конкретно Вашей задачи (а не задачи с неизвестным количеством чисел в списке), мне кажется будет решением **в лоб**. У нас есть всего три возможных пары с индексами `[(0, 1), (2, 3)], [(0, 2), (1, 3)], [(0, 3), (1, 2)]`. Других пар пар в последовательности из четырех чисел нет. Вот и надо написать функцию, которая сравнит эти три пары по суммам.